# forbid someone to do something

Tags: to-infinitive

"They forbid people to enter their building."

Do we see 'to enter their building' or 'people to enter their building' as the object? And also, even if someone says that the to-inf. is the object complement, and it's just that there is no 'not' in front of the to-inf because if it were so, than the negative meaning doubles; they are just making a mistake in diagnosing their sensation of the negative meanings doubling, because the reason of the sensation is that '(people) to enter their building' is the object of 'forbid', subconscious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **forbid** is not used very much these days, but **allow** uses the same structure, so I will explain using examples of **allow**.

Generally, **allow** takes two objects. Here is the clearest form:

> She allows her children an hour of computer games before bedtime

The first object is the beneficiary **her children** and the second object is the benefit **an hour of computer games before bedtime**.

We can change the benefit to a to-verb:

> She allows her children to play computer games before bedtime

We can negate it in one of two ways, with different meanings

> She does not allow her children to play computer games
> She allows her children to not play computer games

The first means that she never allows the beneficiaries enjoy a benefit. The second means that she does not force the beneficiaries to enjoy a benefit.

We can also use a gerund in place of a to-infinitive: generally the beneficiary is omitted, and passive mood is often used:

> The company does not allow smoking on the premises.
> smoking is not allowed on the premises.

The second sentence is passive voice, and so the subject (the company) is omitted , the benefit appears as the patient, and the beneficiary is omitted. The same sentence can also be written with the beneficiary appearing as the patient and the benefit as a to-infinitive but not a gerund:

> people are not allowed to smoke on the premises.

Comment: Then, you're saying the inf. is the Od and 'people' the Oi? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: In my opinion, the terms direct object and indirect object work well with verbs where the indirect object is marked by a to-preposition (give, send) or by a for-preposition (make, get) when placed after the direct object, and where this preposition is omitted if the indirect object is placed before the direct object, eg "send him a email". There are other verbs where neither object takes a preposition: forbid, allow, permit: for these, it is better to think of them as "two objects", without classifying them as direct or indirect.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.